# Viewing application on fan page using test user/test account

Tags: facebook, testing, account

I am using Selenium to do some testing bits and pieces so have created myself a test account successfully.

The problem that I'm having is that when I view most fan pages I can not see any of the applications that I would like to test. Accessing the application directly doesn't work either.

However, one of my fan pages does show one of the applications but the rest don't and I have no idea why.

I have double checked this on facebook.com/disney and again I can't see any of their application links.

Can test accounts even "see" applications? Do I need to modify my test user in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign test users to your application in the App Settings.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was using the wrong appId and secret. Works fine now.